# Usando o método de triangularização inferior calcular o determinante de uma matriz transposta

Tags: c, matriz

Usando o método de triangularização inferior, eu tenho que calcular o determinante de uma matriz transposta.

Eu estou querendo, a partir da matriz transposta, calcular o determinante usando para isso o método de triangularização inferior, pois o determinante tem que ser igual ao determinante da matriz original.

A matriz transposta já está no código, eu não estou conseguindo é fazer a triangularização para depois calcular o determinante.

Segue o código:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

#define linhas 2
#define colunas 2

void main(){

    double mat[linhas][colunas] = { 1, 4, 7, 3 };
    // double mat[linhas][colunas] = { {2, -4, 8}, {5, 4, 6}, {-3, 0, 2} };
    // double mat[linhas][colunas] = { 1, 4, 7, 3, 2, 6, -3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 6, 8, -2, 5, -1 };
    // double mat[linhas][colunas] = { 1, 4, 7, 3, 2, 6, -3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 6, 8, -2, 5, -1, 0, 1, -7, -5, 4, 6, -10.5, 0, -5 };

    double det=1, mult, aux;

    int i, j, pivo; //indices para efetuar modificações na matriz
    int a, b; //indices apenas para debugar a modificação da matriz
    int r, l, inicio;
    int p, c;

    printf("\nMatriz antes do cálculo\n");
    for(a=0; a<linhas; a++){
        for(b=0; b<colunas; b++)
        printf("%.2f\t", mat[a][b]);
    printf("\n");
}
    printf("\n");

    aux= mat[linhas][colunas];
    mat[linhas][colunas] = mat[colunas][linhas];
    mat[colunas][linhas] = aux;
    printf("\nMatriz transposta é\n");
    for(a=0; a<colunas; a++){
        for(b=0; b<linhas; b++)
    printf("%.2f\t",mat[b][a]);
    printf("\n");
}
    printf("\n");

    //Triangulizando a matriz
    for(pivo=0; pivo>linhas; pivo--){

    for(i=pivo-1; i>linhas; i--){

    mult=(-1)*mat[i][pivo]/mat[pivo][pivo];

    for(j=0; j>colunas; j--){
        mat[i][j] = mat[i][j] + (mult*mat[pivo][j]);
        }//fim for j

    printf("Matriz alterada com pivo=%d, i=%d\n", pivo,i);
    for(a=0; a<linhas; a++){
        for(b=0; b<colunas; b++)
        printf("%.2f\t", mat[a][b]);
        printf("\n");
}//fim for a

}//fim for i
}//fim for pivo
//fim da triangulização da matriz. Pronto para cálculo do determinante



   //calculando determinante
    for(i=0; i<linhas; i++){
        printf("mat[%d][%d] = %.2f\n",i , i, mat[i][i]);
        det=det*mat[i][i];
    }//fim cálculo do determinante
    printf("\nDeterminante = %.2f\n", det);

    printf("\nMatriz após o cálculo\n");
    for(a=0; a<linhas; a++){
        for(b=0; b<colunas; b++)
        printf("%.2f\t", mat[a][b]);
    printf("\n");
    }//fim for a
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Pelo visto você é novo aqui, então pra começar, sempre que você faz uma pergunta, você precisa detalhar sua dúvida e o que realmente está te perturbando ou atrapalhando, assim poderemos te ajudar :). Seja direto, nada de enrolação, mas conte tudo que possa colaborar para uma resposta que lhe ajude.

Comment: Ola Alan, nao estou conseguindo entender seu problema, sugiro vc editar sua pergunta e adicionar mais informações a ela.

Comment: Dê uma olhada em outras perguntas para se ter ideia de como se deve prosseguir em um questionamento. Algo que também pode lhe ajudar é a área de [ajuda do stackoverflow](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Então eu estou querendo é, a partir da matriz transposta calcular o determinante usando para isso o método de triangularização inferior, pois o determinante tem que ser igual ao determinante da matriz original, a matriz transposta já está no código, eu não estou conseguindo é fazer a triangularização para depois calcular o determinante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Primeiras pequenas correções e melhorias

Primeiramente, olhe isso:

```c
double mat[linhas][colunas] = { 1, 4, 7, 3 };
```

Isso não é uma matriz 2x2! Isso é um vetor de 4 posições. O que você queria era isso:

```c
double mat[linhas][colunas] = { {1, 4}, {7, 3} };
```

Também dá para simplificar isso:

```c
det=det*mat[i][i];
```

Para isso:

```c
det *= mat[i][i];
```

E isso:

```c
mat[i][j] = mat[i][j] + (mult*mat[pivo][j]);
```

Para isso:

```c
mat[i][j] += mult * mat[pivo][j];
```

Vamos dar uma melhor olhada nisso:

## 2. O erro na triangularização

Vamos dar uma olhada neste trecho do seu código:

```c
    for(pivo=0; pivo>linhas; pivo--){

    for(i=pivo-1; i>linhas; i--){

    mult=(-1)*mat[i][pivo]/mat[pivo][pivo];

    for(j=0; j>colunas; j--){
```

Observe a condição dos seus três `for`s estão totalmente erradas! `pivo>linhas`, `i>linhas` e `j>colunas` são condições que sempre serão falsas. Acho que o que você queria era isso:

```c
    for (pivo = linhas - 1; pivo >= 0; pivo--) {

        for (i = pivo - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            mult = (-1) * mat[i][pivo] / mat[pivo][pivo];

            for (j = colunas - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                mat[i][j] += mult * mat[pivo][j];
            } // Fim do for j.
```

## 3. A transposição que não faz nada

E também, observe isso:

```c
    aux = mat[linhas][colunas];
    mat[linhas][colunas] = mat[colunas][linhas];
    mat[colunas][linhas] = aux;
```

Dado que a matriz é quadrada, então sempre teremos que `linhas = colunas`. Supondo que `linhas = colunas = N`, para algum valor inteiro `N`, teremos isso:

```c
    aux = mat[N][N];
    mat[N][N] = mat[N][N];
    mat[N][N] = aux;
```

A linha do meio é completamente desnecessária, logo isso é reduzido para:

```c
    aux = mat[N][N];
    mat[N][N] = aux;
```

E isso efetivamente não faz nada! Logo, pode ser eliminado. Ao eliminar isso, a variável `aux` não é mais necessária.

Há mais um porém neste trecho. Em uma matriz NxN, os índices das linhas e colunas vão de 0 até `N-1`, e portanto acessar `mat[N][N]` é acessar uma região de memória fora da matriz. Ainda bem que essa parte do código pode ser simplesmente eliminada.

## 4. O código revisado

Feitas as correções acima, vamos reidentar o seu código e eliminar as variáveis que não são usadas (`aux`, `r`, `l`, `inicio`, `p` e `c`). Também estou movendo `det` e `mult` para serem declaradas apenas quando serão necessárias. Uma vez que apenas matrizes quadradas têm sentido, então podemos unificar `linhas` e `colunas` em uma coisa só, chamada `tamanho`. Também aproveito para fazer `main` retornar `int` ao invés de `void`. E finalmente, o seu código completo revisado fica assim:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

#define tamanho 2

int main() {

    double mat[tamanho][tamanho] = { {1, 4}, {7, 3} };
    // double mat[tamanho][tamanho] = { {2, -4, 8}, {5, 4, 6}, {-3, 0, 2} };
    // double mat[tamanho][tamanho] = { {1, 4, 7, 3}, {2, 6, -3, 0}, {2, 1, 3, 6}, {8, -2, 5, -1} };
    // double mat[tamanho][tamanho] = { {1, 4, 7, 3, 2}, {6, -3, 0, 2, 1}, {3, 6, 8, -2, 5}, {-1, 0, 1, -7, -5}, {4, 6, -10.5, 0, -5} };

    int i, j, pivo; // Índices para efetuar modificações na matriz.
    int a, b; // Índices apenas para debugar a modificaçõo da matriz.

    printf("\nMatriz antes do cálculo\n");
    for (a = 0; a < tamanho; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b < tamanho; b++) {
            printf("%.2f\t", mat[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("\nMatriz transposta é\n");
    for (a = 0; a < tamanho; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b < tamanho; b++) {
            printf("%.2f\t", mat[b][a]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Triangularizando a matriz.
    for (pivo = tamanho - 1; pivo >= 0; pivo--) {

        for (i = pivo - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            double mult = (-1) * mat[i][pivo] / mat[pivo][pivo];

            for (j = tamanho - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                mat[i][j] += mult * mat[pivo][j];
            } // Fim do for j.

            printf("Matriz alterada com pivo=%d, i=%d\n", pivo, i);
            for (a = 0; a < tamanho; a++) {
                for (b = 0; b < tamanho; b++) {
                    printf("%.2f\t", mat[a][b]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            } // Fim do for a.

        } // Fim do for i.
    } // Fim do for pivo.
    // Fim da triangularização da matriz. Pronto para o cálculo do determinante.

    // Calculando determinante.
    double det = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        printf("mat[%d][%d] = %.2f\n", i, i, mat[i][i]);
        det *= mat[i][i];
    } // Fim do cálculo do determinante.
    printf("\nDeterminante = %.2f\n", det);

    printf("\nMatriz após o cálculo\n");
    for (a = 0; a < tamanho; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b < tamanho; b++) {
            printf("%.2f\t", mat[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } // Fim do for a.
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

## 5. Testando o código

E então, eis o resultado para a matriz 2x2:

```
Matriz antes do cálculo
1.00    4.00    
7.00    3.00    


Matriz transposta é
1.00    7.00    
4.00    3.00    

Matriz alterada com pivo=1, i=0
-8.33   0.00    
7.00    3.00    
mat[0][0] = -8.33
mat[1][1] = 3.00

Determinante = -25.00

Matriz após o cálculo
-8.33   0.00    
7.00    3.00
```

Para a matriz 3x3:

```
Matriz antes do cálculo
2.00    -4.00   8.00    
5.00    4.00    6.00    
-3.00   0.00    2.00    


Matriz transposta é
2.00    5.00    -3.00   
-4.00   4.00    0.00    
8.00    6.00    2.00    

Matriz alterada com pivo=2, i=1
2.00    -4.00   8.00    
14.00   4.00    0.00    
-3.00   0.00    2.00    
Matriz alterada com pivo=2, i=0
14.00   -4.00   0.00    
14.00   4.00    0.00    
-3.00   0.00    2.00    
Matriz alterada com pivo=1, i=0
28.00   0.00    0.00    
14.00   4.00    0.00    
-3.00   0.00    2.00    
mat[0][0] = 28.00
mat[1][1] = 4.00
mat[2][2] = 2.00

Determinante = 224.00

Matriz após o cálculo
28.00   0.00    0.00    
14.00   4.00    0.00    
-3.00   0.00    2.00
```

Para a matriz 4x4:

```
Matriz antes do cálculo
1.00    4.00    7.00    3.00    
2.00    6.00    -3.00   0.00    
2.00    1.00    3.00    6.00    
8.00    -2.00   5.00    -1.00   


Matriz transposta é
1.00    2.00    2.00    8.00    
4.00    6.00    1.00    -2.00   
7.00    -3.00   3.00    5.00    
3.00    0.00    6.00    -1.00   

Matriz alterada com pivo=3, i=2
1.00    4.00    7.00    3.00    
2.00    6.00    -3.00   0.00    
50.00   -11.00  33.00   0.00    
8.00    -2.00   5.00    -1.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=3, i=1
1.00    4.00    7.00    3.00    
2.00    6.00    -3.00   0.00    
50.00   -11.00  33.00   0.00    
8.00    -2.00   5.00    -1.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=3, i=0
25.00   -2.00   22.00   0.00    
2.00    6.00    -3.00   0.00    
50.00   -11.00  33.00   0.00    
8.00    -2.00   5.00    -1.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=2, i=1
25.00   -2.00   22.00   0.00    
6.55    5.00    0.00    0.00    
50.00   -11.00  33.00   0.00    
8.00    -2.00   5.00    -1.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=2, i=0
-8.33   5.33    0.00    0.00    
6.55    5.00    0.00    0.00    
50.00   -11.00  33.00   0.00    
8.00    -2.00   5.00    -1.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=1, i=0
-15.32  -0.00   0.00    0.00    
6.55    5.00    0.00    0.00    
50.00   -11.00  33.00   0.00    
8.00    -2.00   5.00    -1.00   
mat[0][0] = -15.32
mat[1][1] = 5.00
mat[2][2] = 33.00
mat[3][3] = -1.00

Determinante = 2527.00

Matriz após o cálculo
-15.32  -0.00   0.00    0.00    
6.55    5.00    0.00    0.00    
50.00   -11.00  33.00   0.00    
8.00    -2.00   5.00    -1.00
```

Para a matriz 5x5:

```
Matriz antes do cálculo
1.00    4.00    7.00    3.00    2.00    
6.00    -3.00   0.00    2.00    1.00    
3.00    6.00    8.00    -2.00   5.00    
-1.00   0.00    1.00    -7.00   -5.00   
4.00    6.00    -10.50  0.00    -5.00   


Matriz transposta é
1.00    6.00    3.00    -1.00   4.00    
4.00    -3.00   6.00    0.00    6.00    
7.00    0.00    8.00    1.00    -10.50  
3.00    2.00    -2.00   -7.00   0.00    
2.00    1.00    5.00    -5.00   -5.00   

Matriz alterada com pivo=4, i=3
1.00    4.00    7.00    3.00    2.00    
6.00    -3.00   0.00    2.00    1.00    
3.00    6.00    8.00    -2.00   5.00    
-5.00   -6.00   11.50   -7.00   0.00    
4.00    6.00    -10.50  0.00    -5.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=4, i=2
1.00    4.00    7.00    3.00    2.00    
6.00    -3.00   0.00    2.00    1.00    
7.00    12.00   -2.50   -2.00   0.00    
-5.00   -6.00   11.50   -7.00   0.00    
4.00    6.00    -10.50  0.00    -5.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=4, i=1
1.00    4.00    7.00    3.00    2.00    
6.80    -1.80   -2.10   2.00    -0.00   
7.00    12.00   -2.50   -2.00   0.00    
-5.00   -6.00   11.50   -7.00   0.00    
4.00    6.00    -10.50  0.00    -5.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=4, i=0
2.60    6.40    2.80    3.00    -0.00   
6.80    -1.80   -2.10   2.00    -0.00   
7.00    12.00   -2.50   -2.00   0.00    
-5.00   -6.00   11.50   -7.00   0.00    
4.00    6.00    -10.50  0.00    -5.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=3, i=2
2.60    6.40    2.80    3.00    -0.00   
6.80    -1.80   -2.10   2.00    -0.00   
8.43    13.71   -5.79   -0.00   0.00    
-5.00   -6.00   11.50   -7.00   0.00    
4.00    6.00    -10.50  0.00    -5.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=3, i=1
2.60    6.40    2.80    3.00    -0.00   
5.37    -3.51   1.19    0.00    -0.00   
8.43    13.71   -5.79   -0.00   0.00    
-5.00   -6.00   11.50   -7.00   0.00    
4.00    6.00    -10.50  0.00    -5.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=3, i=0
0.46    3.83    7.73    0.00    -0.00   
5.37    -3.51   1.19    0.00    -0.00   
8.43    13.71   -5.79   -0.00   0.00    
-5.00   -6.00   11.50   -7.00   0.00    
4.00    6.00    -10.50  0.00    -5.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=2, i=1
0.46    3.83    7.73    0.00    -0.00   
7.10    -0.70   -0.00   0.00    -0.00   
8.43    13.71   -5.79   -0.00   0.00    
-5.00   -6.00   11.50   -7.00   0.00    
4.00    6.00    -10.50  0.00    -5.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=2, i=0
11.72   22.15   -0.00   0.00    -0.00   
7.10    -0.70   -0.00   0.00    -0.00   
8.43    13.71   -5.79   -0.00   0.00    
-5.00   -6.00   11.50   -7.00   0.00    
4.00    6.00    -10.50  0.00    -5.00   
Matriz alterada com pivo=1, i=0
235.14  0.00    -0.00   0.00    -0.00   
7.10    -0.70   -0.00   0.00    -0.00   
8.43    13.71   -5.79   -0.00   0.00    
-5.00   -6.00   11.50   -7.00   0.00    
4.00    6.00    -10.50  0.00    -5.00   
mat[0][0] = 235.14
mat[1][1] = -0.70
mat[2][2] = -5.79
mat[3][3] = -7.00
mat[4][4] = -5.00

Determinante = 33507.50

Matriz após o cálculo
235.14  0.00    -0.00   0.00    -0.00   
7.10    -0.70   -0.00   0.00    -0.00   
8.43    13.71   -5.79   -0.00   0.00    
-5.00   -6.00   11.50   -7.00   0.00    
4.00    6.00    -10.50  0.00    -5.00
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone](http://ideone.com/ZydZly).

## 6. Divisão por zero

Ah, a ainda um último detalhe a se ver. Observe essa linha no processo de triangularização:

```
double mult = (-1) * mat[i][pivo] / mat[pivo][pivo];
```

O que acontece se houver um zero em um dos elementos da diagonal principal? O resultado é que vai dar pau ao tentar dividir por zero!

Para resolver isso, sugiro que antes de efetuar uma etapa na triangularização, que se `mat[pivo][pivo]` for zero, que você faça uma permutação entre duas linhas ou duas colunas de forma a tentar nunca deixar zeros da diagonal principal. Lembre-se também que cada vez que você fizer uma permutação dessas, o sinal do determinante se inverte.

Se não for possível tirar algum zero da diagonal principal ao permutar duas linhas ou duas colunas, então isso significa que há uma linha ou uma coluna só com zeros. E se for este o caso, então você pode parar os cálculos da triangularização porque o determinante resultante será sempre zero.